# Proving $\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{e^x -1}{x} =1$ using epsilon delta and the continuity of $e^x$ at $0$

Tags: calculus, analysis, epsilon-delta

> Proving $\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{e^x -1}{x} =1$ using epsilon delta and the continuity of $e^x$ at $0$.

Knowing that $e^x$ is continous at 1, I want to proof the limit
$\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{e^x -1}{x} =1$ using an epsilon-delta proof. I reasoned as follows:

Let $\varepsilon$ be greater than 0 an suppose that
$$\left|\frac{e^x-1}{x} -1\right|<\varepsilon$$

This means that
$$-\varepsilon -1 < -\varepsilon +1 < \frac{e^x -1}{x} < \varepsilon +1$$
Then,

$$\frac{|e^x-1|}{|x|}=\left|\frac{e^x-1}{x}\right|<\varepsilon+1$$. So, if I multiply both sides by |x| we have that
$$|e^x -1|<|x|(\varepsilon+1)$$

Let $\varepsilon_2 = |x|(\varepsilon +1)$. Since we know that $e^x$ is continous at x=1 we then have that there exists $\delta$ such that
$$0<|x|<\delta \Rightarrow |e^x -1|<\varepsilon_2$$
which then, by replacing the definition of $\varepsilon_2$ implies
$$0<|x|<\delta \Rightarrow\left|\frac{e^x-1}{x} -1\right|<\varepsilon$$

Although it might be convincing, I'm having a hard time to check whether the step of naming $\varepsilon_2=|x|(\varepsilon+1)$ is indeed valid for the proof.

Comment: Hi, welcome to MSE. You can use $$e^x\sim 1+x+\frac {x^2}{2}$$

Comment: There exists $\delta(\varepsilon_2)>0$ (depending *only* on the number $\varepsilon_2>0$) such that $|x|<\delta(\varepsilon_2)\implies|e^x-a|<\varepsilon_2$. Here, $\varepsilon_2$ cannot be a function of $x$ like $|x|(\varepsilon+1)$. Moreover, $|e^x -1|<|x|(\varepsilon+1)$ does not imply $\left|\frac{e^x-1}{x} -1\right|<\varepsilon$. Anyway, how can you dream of deriving differentiability from continuity?

Comment: That said, there are a lot of correct proofs on this site https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=AND%20site%3Amath.stackexchange.com%2C%20OR%20content%3A%24%5Clim_%7Bx%5Cto%200%7D%20%5Cfrac%7Be%5Ex%20-1%7D%7Bx%7D%3D1%24&p=1 (using of course more than continuity)

Comment: [This](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2150480) might interest you!

Comment: It will be impossible to prove this fact using just the fact that $e^x-1$ is continuous at $0$ and has value $0$. For instance, $f(x) = x^{1/3}$ has the same property but $\lim_{x\to 0} f(x)/x$ does not exist

Comment: Adding to what vujazzman said: at some place you will have to use special properties of $e$. For example, suppose you replaced $e$ by $2$; then the claim wouldn't be true. And yet you haven't used anything about $e$.

Answer (score 0):

First of all by Archimedian Property we know that for some $\epsilon_2$=$|x|$ $\exists N\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $\frac{1}{N}<\epsilon_2 \Rightarrow |x|>\frac{1}{N_1}$ after that we need to get the inequality.
Pick $\delta :=min(1,N_1)$ and $\epsilon_1 = eN_1+N_1+1$ after that we have two inequalities   $-1<x<1 \Rightarrow e>e^x>0$ and which comes from Archimeadian property. Then obtain;
$|\frac{e^x-1}{x}-1|\leq \frac{|e^x-1|}{|x|}+1\leq (e^x+1).N_1+1\leq\ eN_1+N_1+1\leq \epsilon_1 $ then  we are done.

Comment: I tried something like that if anything doesn't seem right please correct me.

Comment: Welcome to Maths StackExchange. The issue with your solution is that you need to take an arbitrary positive $\epsilon_{1}$ and show that there is some positive $\delta$ such that $\left| \frac{e^{x} - 1}{x} - 1\right| < \epsilon_{1}$ whenever $0 < |x| < \delta$. However, you have allowed $\epsilon_{1}$ to be determined by your choice of $N$, and you do not obtain all possible positive values of $\epsilon_{1}$ this way. So the proof does not follow from your argument. In addition, please explain your ideas with words rather than using symbols such as $\exists$ and $\Rightarrow$ in the future.